# Meaning of 何によらず

Tags: meaning, expressions

I was reading a Japanese sentence of which part read

> 生真面目な性格で、**何によらず**人の注目を引くことが苦手だった。

but could not work out the meaning of 何によらず. I thought that perhaps the よらず is the negative of よる but that still didn't make sense to me.

Just wondering if anyone has come across this before and know what it means. Any help much appreciated.

The meanings of the other words in that sentence are

- 生真面目【きまじめ】 *too serious, a person who is too serious*
- 性格【せいかく】 *character, personality*

Comment: Could you provide the whole sentence? This 何によらず should be an adverbial phrase which modifies something after 人.

Comment: Hi again.. the full sentence is 生真面目な性格で、何によらず人の注目を引くこと苦手だった。

Comment: Are you sure it's ...引くこと苦手だった instead of ...引くこと**が**苦手だった? (If yes, that's a typo anyway...)

Comment: yes you're right! there is a 'ga' before 'nigate' and after 'koto'..thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the feeling the meaning of the sentence is something like "as a very serious person he was unable to make a splash out of anything"..or something like that..it seems to be talking about how someone is boring and they can't get people's attention

Comment: @Rowan It would depend on the context, but I feel you're still translating this sentence a bit too negatively. Basically this sentence just says he was a earnest, shy guy.

Answer (score 4):

何によらず (literally "regardless of whatever") indicates that the following part applies for every respect. I think you can translate it using "in all respects", "in every way", "whatever it is", "whatsoever", "all sorts of", etc.

何事【なにごと】によらず means the same, and is more common, according to [BCCWJ Corpus](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/).

By the way, 生真面目 does not necessarily have the negative connotation, and it can just mean *very serious* or *earnest*.

Answer (score 1):

によらず　means regardless of

for example：
すなわち，血によらず，肉によらず，人によらず，神によって生まれた人々である
who were born not of blood, nor of the will of the flesh, nor of the will of man, but of God.

Comment: http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A

Comment: You found the right page and why not quote the right example? 「 **何事によらず**粗末にするな **Whatever the matter may be,―Be the matter what it may,** ―do your best.」